# Not able to invoke gnome-terminal on ubuntu with python subprocess

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, gnome-terminal

**UseCase:**
i need to run a command on two separate gnome terminal.

command is 'appium -p port' , where port is a list which contains two port number.
so the final command would be like

appium -p 4723

appium -p 4750

Here is my code

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

def open_ubuntu_appium(*args):
        for item in args:
            for subitem in item:
                subitem=str(subitem)
                command='appium -p'
                command ='"'+command+' '+subitem+';read -n1" '
                print command
                #"appium -p 4723;read -n1"
                #"appium -p 4750;read -n1"
                subitem = Popen(['gnome-terminal','--disable-factory','-x','bash','-c',command],preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

port=[4723,4750]
appium=open_ubuntu_appium(port)
```

Output :
No gnome terminal invoked

Expected :
Two separate Gnome terminal should invoke with command

appium -p 4723

appium -p 4750

what wrong i am doing here , is there any other way i can achieve this.
I also need to kill the invoked terminal after their launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am still not able to solve the above issue, however i found an alternative to open multiple terminal in ubuntu

```
    from subprocess import Popen
    def open_appium(*args):
        command='appium -p'
        linux_terminal=['gnome-terminal']
            for item in args:
                for port in item:
                    linux_terminal.extend((['--tab','--disable-factory','-e', '''
                    bash -c '
                    echo "%(command)s %(port)s"
                    %(command)s "%(port)s"
                    read
                    '    
                    ''' % locals()]))
            linux_window=Popen(terminal,preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

port=[4723,4730]
ab=open_appium(port)
```

Output :
Two separate gnome terminal would be invoked with the "appium -p" + port  command